# NullPointerException when tyring to create table for mapped-superclass

Tags: jpa, datanucleus

I traced it down to the getDatastoreClass returning a null datastore class to the createPerImplementationColumnsForReferenceField.

I have tried both the 3.1.1 and now using 3.2.0-m4 release hoping that would fix my problem.

```
RDBMSStoreManager#getDatastoreClass(String className, ClassLoaderResolver clr);
```

It is returning a null datastore class to the

```
ReferenceMapping#createPerImplementationColumnsForReferenceField(boolean pk, boolean nullable, boolean serialised, boolean embedded, int fieldRole, ColumnMetaData[] columnMetaData, ClassLoaderResolver clr)
```

I am using the orm to annotate a mapped-superclass and this mapped-superclass does not have a table definition and both of my mapped-superclass throwing this exception.

```
499170 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema  - Field [com.hp.vf.server.domain.AlertDefinition.isPublic] -> Column(s) ["ALERTDEFINITION"."ISPUBLIC"] using mapping of type "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.BooleanMapping" (org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.datastore.SmallIntRDBMSMapping)
551964 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG DataNucleus.Persistence  - Managing Persistence of Class : com.hp.vf.analytics.shared.metric.Metric [Table : (none), InheritanceStrategy : subclass-table]
561964 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema  - An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.ReferenceMapping.createPerImplementationColumnsForReferenceField(ReferenceMapping.java:452)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.ReferenceMapping.prepareDatastoreMapping(ReferenceMapping.java:214)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.ReferenceMapping.initialize(ReferenceMapping.java:110)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.InterfaceMapping.initialize(InterfaceMapping.java:54)
```

In the Reference mapping, dc is null when trying to execute getIdMapping(), I have verified this in the debugger.

```
           try
            {
                DatastoreClass dc = storeMgr.getDatastoreClass(implClass.getName(), clr);
                m = dc.getIdMapping(); // DC is null 
            }
            catch (NoTableManagedException ex)
            {
                // TODO Localise this message
                throw new NucleusUserException("Cannot define columns for " + mmd.getFullFieldName() + 
                    " due to " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
```

Here is the problematic class file.

```
public abstract class Metric implements IMetric {

    /**
     * Serialization ID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3806479436166940035L;

    private Long id;

    /**
     * The name of the metric, this is not mandatory we have some metrics that
     * may come back without names.
     */
    protected String name;

    /**
     * This is an optional metric value that can be set by the script in order
     * to add context to the execution of the metric.
     */
    protected String context;

    /**
     * The list of violations associated with this metric.
     */
    protected List<Violation> violations = null;

    public Metric() {
        violations = new ArrayList<Violation>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that takes the name of the object and the value that it
     * represents.
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    public Metric(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#getName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#setName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * This is the context that represents the metric. This could have come from
     * R and would be a Key:Value; pair of values used to calculate the value.
     * For example if a metric was calculated for a product in houston for ISS
     * the context may look like "ProdNum:1234;Factory:Houston;BUnit:ISS". This
     * context is useful when chaining together tasks.
     * 
     * @return String context used when chaining tasks together.
     */
    public String getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#toString()
     */
    public String toString() {
        String debugString = "";
        debugString += "Metric: " + name;

        return debugString;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#hasMetricViolations()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasMetricViolations() {
        return (violations != null && violations.size() > 0) ? true : false;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#getViolations()
     */
    @Override
    public List<IViolation> getViolations() {
        return violations;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.hp.vf.taskengine.shared.metric.IMetric#setViolations(java.util.List)
     */
    @Override
    public void setViolations(List<IViolation> violations) {
        this.violations = violations;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is an excert from my orm.xml file

```
<access>FIELD</access>

<mapped-superclass class="com.hp.vf.analytics.shared.metric.Metric" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="name" />
        <basic name="context" />
        <one-to-many name="violations">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: you have some field that is an interface (well a reference field, so may be interface or may be java.lang.Object) and you don't show the class that has this field. Ho hum

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. I was exhausted by the time I posted the the question and can't believe I didn't poost the class. I believe you are exactly right although I didn't see anything specific in the enhancer when when enhancing but debug was enabled so I may have missed it. I am pretty sure I need to add the target entity to the one-to-many for the violations class. What is strange though is that it worked 50% of the time. I wrote a unit test to save an extended metric class and it would complete successfully every other run. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Presumably Violation is the interface type there. No idea about your problem; I use JPA with Set fields of an interface type marked as @OneToMany and work for me all of the time, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/orm/interfaces.html  but then that does say clearly enough to use a join table and be unidirectional

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem using the tips from Datanucleus. I had multiple problems

**Problems**
The most obvious and silly on my part

**If you have an one-to-many or one-to-one that uses an interface you must specify the target-entity.**

```
    /**
     * The list of violations associated with this metric.
     */
    protected List<IViolation> violations = null;
...
    <one-to-many name="violations"
      target-entity="com.vf.analytics.shared.metric.Violation">
       <cascade>
          <cascade-all />
       </cascade>
    </one-to-many>
```

**Don't use generics, the jpa spec does not suppport them** 
*Not sure if datanucleus supports generics but it but probably not recommended.*

```
public MetricNumber< T extends Number> extends Metric implements IMetric {
  T value;
}
```

**If you extend an entity that is not annotated make sure that you add it to your orm.xml**

I wasn't testing some of the objects so I assumed that datanucleus would ignore them but this appears not to be the case. I had extended third party classes that were not annotated but had not yet added them to the orm.xml, this was also causing null the null pointer exceptions I was getting.